# Using attr_accessor from inside class?

Tags: ruby, attr-accessor

I'm trying to use an `attr_accessor` from inside the class where it is defined, to no avail. Why does this not work?

I would expect the following to output "new" in IRB:

```
irb(main):016:0> foo = StringClass.new
=> #<StringClass:0x2fbf2c0 @thing="old">
irb(main):017:0> foo.output
old
=> nil
irb(main):018:0> foo.change
=> "new"
irb(main):021:0> foo.output
old
=> nil
```

Here's the implementation:

```
class StringClass
  def initialize
    @thing = "old"
  end

  attr_accessor :thing

  def output
    puts thing
  end

  def change
    thing = "new"
  end
end
```

I can see that the `thing=` method is defined. I don't understand why that method is not being called when I try changing the value.

Comment: Thanks, you're right this is a duplicate. How best to resolve?

Comment: Since you are only referencing the instance variable from within the class, maybe it is better to dispense with the attr_accessor and simply use the @ symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is, because those methods should be called with `self`:

```
class StringClass
  def initialize
    @thing = "old"
  end

  attr_accessor :thing

  def output
    puts self.thing
  end

  def change
    self.thing = "new"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I really don't understand why though, when one doesn't have to do that for methods defined 'normally'.

Comment: @Deejay - with syntaxt "without" `self`, Ruby doesn't know if you're trying to call a method (you know it, because you understand the context), or just want to create a local variable. If you don't specify `self` - it'll create a local variable in this case

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
class StringClass
   ......

   def change
     self.thing = "new"
   end
 end
```

1. foo = StringClass.new
2. foo.change => "new"